# Morris js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I'm trying to get a Morris JS graph displaying data coming from a Servlet.

Here is the JS code:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/GetStat1',
    type : 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    success : function(responseJson) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseJson)));

        new Morris.Line({
          element: 'morrischartTAG',
          data:  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseJson)),
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          labels: ['TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG3'],
          ymax: 'auto 300',
          resize: true
        });
    }
  });
```

Data retrieved in the responseJson is the following:
`[{y:'2020-08',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2020-07',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2020-06',a:94,b:0,c:0},{y:'2020-05',a:3,b:0,c:0},{y:'2020-04',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2020-03',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2020-02',a:1,b:0,c:0},{y:'2020-01',a:1,b:0,c:0},{y:'2019-12',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2019-11',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2019-10',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2019-09',a:0,b:0,c:0},{y:'2019-08',a:0,b:0,c:0}]`

If I copy the content of responseJson literally into data, the graph is displayed successfully si I assume this is a problem of JSON conversion but I'm not able to find a solution even by looking at the older posts highlighting similar issue....

My servlet is just sending Data like this:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(finalStatYear);
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Any help will be appreciated !